# Removing punctuation between two words

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) and I would like to remove punctuation.

However there an issue with dot between 2 words and at the end of one word like this:

```
test.
test1.test2
```

I use this to remove the punctuation:

```
library(tm)
removePunctuation(df)
```

and the result I take is this:

```
 test
 test1test2
```

but I would like to take this as result:

```
test
test1 test2
```

How is it possible to have a space between two words in the removing process?

Comment: You can use `gsub` i.e. `trimws(gsub('[.]', ' ', str1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to replace the `.` with a white space and remove the trailing/leading spaces (if any) with `trimws`.

```
trimws(gsub('[.]', ' ', str1))
#[1] "test"        "test1 test2"
```

NOTE: In regex, `.` by itself means any character.  So we should either keep it inside square brackets`[.]`) or escape it (`\\.`) or with option `fixed=TRUE`

```
trimws(gsub('.', ' ', str1, fixed=TRUE))
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("test.", "test1.test2")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. As I can see using this `trimws(gsub('.', ' ', str1, fixed=TRUE))` it converts the df to chr?

Comment: @Eracog The output will be a `vector` of `character` class.  If you are applying this on a column of data.frame, use `df1$yourCol <- trimws(gsub".", " ", df1$yourCol, fixed=TRUE))`

Comment: Not sure but this had the levels of the initial df `levels(df$names) <- trimws(gsub('.', ' ', levels(df$names), fixed=TRUE))`

Comment: @Eracog You can use `droplevels` to drop the unused levels if that is what you meant.

Comment: @Eracog I tested your concern.  But, using the example, I get `levels(df$names)
#[1] "test"        "test1 test2"`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `chartr` for single character substitution:

```
chartr(".", " ", c("test1.test2"))
# [1] "test1 test2"
```

@akrun suggested `trimws` to remove the space at the end of your test string:

```
str <- c("test.", "test1.test2")
trimws(chartr(".", " ", str))
# [1] "test"        "test1 test2"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `strsplit`:

```
a <- "test."
b <- "test1.test2"

do.call(paste, as.list(strsplit(a, "\\.")[[1]]))

[1] "test"

do.call(paste, as.list(strsplit(b, "\\.")[[1]]))

[1] "test1 test2"
```